# I can't access my class location from static method

Tags: java

I have to use the getClass method to access the txt file in the data folder in the project files. However, it gives the following error in the code below:
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object

```
public class FileWriting {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {     
            File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/Data/file.txt").toURI());
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);  
            BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(writer);  
            buffer.write("Welcome to javaTpoint.");  
            buffer.close();  
            System.out.println("Success");  
     }  
}
```

Is there anything I can use instead of getClass ()? or how do I use getClass () here?

Comment: Of course you can run getClass(), but you need to run it through an instance of the class, since it's not a static method

Comment: How about using `FileWriting.class` instead of `getClass()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `getClass()` you can use `FileWriting.class`.

The non-static method `getClass()` can't be called from the static main method unless you have an instance of the class. You can however get the class in the static context as shown above.